# php poo carrito

Tags: php, poo

Hola me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error intentando hacer un carrito de compras (que por cierto si tienen forma de ayudarme tirandome tips se los agradeceria):

> Notice: Undefined property: controladorproductos::$codigo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\controlador.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function listar() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\controlador.php on line 18

mis codigos:

conexion

```
<?php

class conexion{

     //Atributos

    private $server;
    private $usuario;
    private $password;
    private $bd;


    //Metodo

    public function __construct(){
          $this->server = "localhost";
          $this->usuario = "root";
          $this->password = "";
          $this->bd = "carro_productos";

          $con = mysql_errno($this->server, $this->usuario, $this->password);
          if ($con) 
            mysql_select_db($this->bs, $con);


    }

   public function consultaSimple($sql){
    $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
   }    

      public function consultaRetorno($sql){

      }


   } 




?>
```

productos

```
<?php

       include_once("conexion.php");
       include_once("carrito.php");
       include_once("controlador.php");
       include_once("enrutador.php");
       include_once("index.php");
       include_once("inicio.php");





       class productos{

        private $codigo;
        private $producto;
        private $descripcion;
        private $precio;

        private $con;

       }

?>
```

controlador

```
<?php


       include_once("productos.php");





       class controladorproductos{
         private $producto;

         public function __construct(){
           $this->productos = new productos();   
         }

         public function index(){
            $resultado = $this->codigo->listar();
            return $resultado;
         }
         public function eliminar($codigo){
            $this->producto->set("codigo", $codigo);
            $this->producto->eliminar();
         }
         public function ver($codigo){
            $this->producto->set("codigo", $codigo);
            $this->producto->ver();
         }

       }
?>
```

enrutador

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
       include_once("carrito.php");
       include_once("controlador.php");
       include_once("enrutador.php");
       include_once("index.php");
       include_once("inicio.php");


class enrutador{
   public function vista($vista){
      switch ($vista):
         case 'añadir':
            include_once($vista . '.php');
            break;

        endswitch;

   }

  public function validarGET($var){
if(empty($var)){
   include_once('inicio.php');
}else{
   return true;
}
  } 


    }


?>
```

index

```
<?php
        include_once("conexion.php");
       include_once("carrito.php");
       include_once("controlador.php");
       include_once("enrutador.php");
       include_once("index.php");
       include_once("inicio.php");



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <title>Carrito</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>
        Carrito
     </h1>

     <section>
     <?php
      $enrutador = new enrutador();
      if($enrutador->validarGET($_GET['añadir'])){
        $enrutador->vista($_GET['añadir']);
      }

      ?>      
     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

inicio

```
<?php 
       include_once("conexion.php");
       include_once("carrito.php");

       include_once("enrutador.php");
       include_once("index.php");
       include_once("inicio.php");


       include_once("controlador.php");

       $controlador = new controladorproductos();
       $resultado = $controlador->index();
?>
<h3>pagina</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>codigo</th>
        <th>producto</th>
        <th>descripción</th>
        <th>precio</th>
        <th>acción</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['codigo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['producto']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['descripción']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['precio']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de la aclaracion de la visibilidad. Tu controlador no tiene la propiedad codigo. Codigo es una propiedad de producto, entonces cuando haces $resultado = $this->codigo->listar(); PHP esta buscando la propiedad codigo en tu controlador y no en la clase producto. Deberia ser algo como $this->producto->codigo.

En tu controlador estas definiendo private $producto; Fijate que the falta la s al final. (private $productos;)

Para conseguir los codigos deberias usar un bucle en ese caso:

```
foreach($this->products as $product) {
  echo $product->codigo;
}
```

Pero fijate que codigo es private. O lo haces public o utiliza un getter

```
public function getCodigo() {
   return $this->codigo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema:

```
     class controladorproductos{
     private $producto;

     public function __construct(){
       $this->productos = new productos();   
     }

     public function index(){
        $resultado = $this->codigo->listar(); #<---------error
        return $resultado;
     }
     public function eliminar($codigo){
        $this->producto->set("codigo", $codigo);
        $this->producto->eliminar();
     }
     public function ver($codigo){
        $this->producto->set("codigo", $codigo);
        $this->producto->ver();
     }

   }
```

en la línea que te marque estás tratando de acceder a un atributo **codigo** en tu objeto controladorproductos el cual no está definido

> $this->codigo

el interprete intenta encontrar ese atributo en el objeto y como no está definido en la clase **controladorproductos** lanza el error

> Notice: Undefined property: controladorproductos::$codigo in C:\xampp\htdocs\controlador.php on line 18

Ahora además de eso intentas llamar al método listar()

> $this->codigo->listar()

Como código no está definido (error anterior) entonces lo que estás haciendo es algo como : `$this->null->listar()` ocasionando el segundo error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function listar() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\controlador.php on line 18

Ahora mejoremos tu clase controlador :

```
class Producto
{
    public $codigo;
    public $producto;
    public $descripcion;
    public $precio;

    private $con;

    public static function listar(filtros){
        //haces el código para crear una consulta con los filtros pasados
    }

    public static function remover(filtros){
        //haces la consulta para eliminar con los filtros
    }

    public static function obtener(filtros){

    }
}


class ControladorProductos //usa CamelCase para el nombre de las clases 
{

     public function __construct(){
       $this->productos = new productos();   
     }

     public function index($codigo=""){
        // usa métodos estáticos para acciones que no tengan que ver con un solo registro
        // listar es un ejemplo de esto usar lo siguiente:
        return Producto::listar(["codigo"=>$codigo])
     }
     public function eliminar($codigo){
        // para remover no necesitas hacer nada mas con el objeto asi que no vale
        // la pena almacenarlo en una variable
        return Producto::remover(['codigo'=>$codigo])
     }
     public function ver($codigo){
        return Producto::obtener(['codigo'=>$codigo])
     }

}
```

si necesitas alguna guía de como hacer puedes guiarte por algún framework de mvc como yii2 o laravel. pero para mejor te recomiendo un el libro :

> POO y MVC en PHP – Eugenia Bahit

si esta aprendiendo php es ideal para usted. si quiere hacer un framework a mano es ideal para usted.